# Synthesis of trans alkene with organoborane

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis

Trans alkenes can be synthesized with organoboranes. The following sequence is represented in Smith's Organic Synthesis
[image]

How does the mechanism look like after the first step (hydroboration)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this might be a alkyl shift that results in an $\mathrm{S}_{N}2$ type substitution at an $sp^{2}$ center. Cool. I've only ever seen $\mathrm{S}_{N}2$ type substitution at an $sp^{2}$ center for vinyl iodides. Unfortunately, I don't have my teaching materials on me at work, so I can't find the reference for this for you.

EDIT:
[image: Mechanism]

Note the "inversion" at the $sp^{2}$ center.

Greg Fu had this great example of a substitution on a vinyl iodide, like I mentioned above. I can't seem to find this reference, but I just emailed him, so I'll update when he writes me back.

Comment: I don’t think it’s a substitution: I would assume addition of methanolate to the boron centre which then induces a migration/insertion of some sort. But I don’t know myself, unfortunately.

Comment: Notice that even in that case, you need inversion of the $sp^2$ center. I am in fact proposing the exact same thing as you are.

Comment: Oh, you’re talking about a formal inversion! I thought you meant an actual inversion =D

Comment: Here's the reference as promised. Somehow my email ended up in Greg Fu's spam folder... :( _JACS_ **1998**, _120_, 2275